# Why does making this Google Sheets formula an ARRAYFORMULA change it's behavior?

Tags: date, datetime, if-statement, google-sheets, string-formatting

This formula works on a per-row basis:

```
=(IF(today()-D2 > 365,text(D2:D,"mmm yyyy"),text(D2:D,"mmm d")))
```

But if I make it an ARRAYFORMUAL like below it always returns text(D2:D,"mmm yyyy") even when **today()-D2 > 365** is False.

```
=arrayformula(IF(LEN(D2:D) = 0, "", (IF(today()-D2 > 365,text(D2:D,"mmm yyyy"),text(D2:D,"mmm d")))))
```

See screenshot below. Column D is the source date. Column F is the ARRAYFORMULA. Column G is the standard formula (hard-coded per row vs ARRAYFORMULA).

I want the ARRAYFORMUAL in column F to replicate the result in column G.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(D2:D), IF((TODAY()-D2:D)>365,
 TEXT(D2:D, "mmm yyyy"), TEXT(D2:D, "mmm d")), ))
```

[image]